# SharePoint Online site and Microsoft Teams Team Relationship

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, team-sites, microsoft-teams

When creating a SharePoint Online site, is a related Microsoft Teams team automatically created?

I understand that when a Microsoft Teams team is created, that a SharePoint site is created.

However, I am interested if the converse is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not create a Microsoft teams team automatically.

When you create a SharePoint online team site it will show you option to create a Microsoft teams and connect the SharePoint site to it in the lower left corner of the home page of your team site:

[image]

Or you can find the **Add real-time chat** entry point in the “Next Steps” panel which is accessible from the top right section of your team site.

[image]

> Team sites that are connected to a Microsoft 365 group in SharePoint can easily add Microsoft Teams. Team sites that *are not* already connected to a group will first need to connect to a Microsoft 365 group before they can be added to Microsoft Teams.

**Reference**: [Create a Microsoft Team from SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-a-microsoft-team-from-sharepoint-545973b6-c38f-426a-b2b6-16405a561628)

Answer (score 4):

Nope, it's not true.

Microsoft Teams = SharePoint Online (Team Site) + Exchange Mailbox + Office 365 Group + Teams mashed together.

- You can create a standalone SharePoint site **without** any association to other Office 365 products. There are 2 common templates: **Communication Site** and **Team Site**. Communication Site usually being deployed for building a company intranet or for any other purposes.
- When you create a SharePoint site with **Team Site** template, it will create an equivalent email address along. You can convert this to Teams by converting it first to an Office 365 Group.
- When you create an Office 365 Group, it will create SharePoint site with an email address. You can convert this into Teams.

Wanna try without messing up your production? You can register yourself as an Office 365 Developer through https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program with a free 90 days brand new Office 365 tenant.